# What should I use to hang a coat hook on a brick wall?

Tags: walls, screws, hanging, anchor

I have purchased several of [these iron coat hooks](http://www.notonthehighstreet.com/theforestandco/product/colourful-metal-hooks):

[image]

However, they do not come with any kind of screws.

I will be hanging them on a (brick + plaster) party wall of my terraced property (UK).

I believe my options are to use either of the following:

- Rawl plugs
- Masonry self-tapping screws

However I am only aware of the latter due to googling for a solution, and I am unsure if either come in sizes suitable for my needs (The screw holes are 4mm in diameter, I am not sure how deep I should drill)

So my question is **what should I use to attach these to the wall?**

Comment: Do you know if the wall is plasterboarded, or plaster directly onto masonry?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a masonry bit and hammer drill to get a hole in brick.

However it may be easier to screw the hooks to a piece of wood and mount the wood to the wall. With a nice routed edge on the wood that can look really nice.

To mount the wood you can use normal masonry anchors.

Comment: Why would screwing into wood help? So I can use larger anchors in the wood than I can on the hooks themselves?

Comment: That was my goal, and you can aim for the mortar and avoid splitting the bricks.

Comment: You'd also need fewer fasteners going into the brick/mortar.

Answer (score 2):

It's a coat hook - it doesn't hold that much weight, and all the force is shear force, not pulling force.

So pretty much anything will work. Simple plastic anchors with screws will work just fine. (Never heard of rawl plugs but google says that that's the same thing as a plastic anchor.)

Masonry screws are a real pain to use if you are not a pro. I would not use those - if you don't get the hole perfect they won't hold. You have to keep the drill very straight and not let it shake and enlarge the hole.

A potential problem: If the plaster is thick make sure the screws are long enough.

Do you have a hammer drill? You'll need one. Practice first on some non-visible concrete or masonry. It can be hard to drill straight, and not drift from your target with one.

Answer (score 1):

If these are only for coats I would glue them up with construction adhesive or silicone.